# React not updating state on fetching API data by hooks

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

I am trying to implement api calls via hooks, but I don't know why the state is not updating . Could someone look at this and tell me the reason:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';

function Weather(){
    var [weat,setWeat]=useState({city:'',report:[]})
    var UpdateCity = event =>{
        setWeat({...weat,city:event.target.value});
    }
    var UpdateReport = event =>{
        var addr="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+weat.city+"&appid=04e"
        console.log(addr);
        fetch(addr)
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(res=>{
            setWeat({...weat,report:res});
        });

    }
    return(
        <>
            <h1>Welcome to my weather App</h1>
            <h3>Please enter your city</h3>
            <input type='text' onChange={UpdateCity} placeholder='Enter your City'></input>
            <input type='submit' onClick={UpdateReport}></input>
        </>
    )
}

export default Weather;
```

Comment: are you passing api key ?

Comment: Yeah , I am passing. I have just masked it here

Comment: try adding the catch block and log error.message then you will be able to see whats the error then update that error in the question so it will be helpful to find it

Comment: Perhaps it'd be easier to just split out your state, use two state hooks and use/update them independently. Or use a state update function, `setWeat(prevWeat => { /* copy, mutate, return */ })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing a key for authentication, so its basically going to error, since you doesn't handle error cases thats why you are not seeing it

So you need to update as follows and pass the key on the url to get the data.

Apart from that code looks fine

```
var UpdateReport = event =>{
        var addr="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+weat.city+"&appid=04e"
        console.log(addr);
        fetch(addr)
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(res=>{
            setWeat({...weat,report:res});
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })

    }
```

**Update**

So the problem was not updating the state, there was a cors issue. See the working codesandbox with a sample api [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/59609653-so-open-weather-map-htiec),

Comment: I am passing the key, I am getting proper  response from the api, but it is not setting the state.

Comment: check this one, the problem was cors issue https://codesandbox.io/s/59609653-so-open-weather-map-htiec, type something and hit submit wait for sometime it will show the response , so if you remove the url cors infront from the get url it will go to catch block so its basically the cors issue, its not related to the state and i get the response as object for the sample so made the state as an object you can update it

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the `s` in your API URL. I believe calls only work through **HTTPS**

```html
https://api.openweathermap.org/.....
```

Also, as @DILEEP THOMAS mention, its better to add `catch` block that will help you know why fetch is not working properly.

```js
.catch(err => console.log(err.message))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code in local and added my own API Key and works out of the box. When testing the app have the chrome console openned and check for the error fetching the data, to see if you have an error on the request.

Also your query might be working and you don't see your component re-render as you are not using `weat` object inside the `return`, please add some log before the return just with this:

```
   console.log("weat.city: ", weat.city, " weat.report: ", weat.report)
   return (
      . . . 
   )
```

So now you will see if the state changes or not.

Comment: Report part is not getting updated. Its still showing empty array :(

Comment: And no errros on the console? On the request tab you should see your request and what responses there ...